# Is it possible to open new tabs/links next to current tab in Chrome?

Tags: applications, settings, chrome-for-android, google, browser

In Chrome (or Chrome Canary), I'd like to be able to open new links/tabs next to the current tab I'm on. If this was on a PC, the equivalent would be tabs/links opened at the top of the tab tree/stack.

The best workaround I've found is selecting any piece of text on the current tab's page, then doing a "web search" from the popup context menu. This opens a tab next to the current tab, then I'll use this tab for what I was wanting to search. This doesn't work for opening links next to the current tab, however. And I'd prefer if this could be done without needing a workaround.